# 'std::bad_alloc' after mistakenly changing /usr/ permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, python

I'm working on a Linux machine running Ubuntu Bionic Beaver, release 18.04.

The other day I mistakenly changed the `/usr/` directory to be owned by a user, instead of root. Unfortunately, I did that recursively, and so messed quite a bit of the system up because it also changed the `suid` permissions on some of the commands (e.g. `passwd`, `sudo`). We really can't reinstall (well we can but it'll cost!), so I booted from a LiveUSB, and changed manually all the correct user/group/permissions for each file that I could identify had a non-`Root:Root` User:Group. I did this by comparing the output of another Ubuntu computer of `ls -lha /usr/`.

It seems to be mostly fixed, but now I'm running into the error 'std::bad_alloc' after running some pretty standard python scripts. The strange part about this is that it only comes up sometimes. For example, if I open python from the command line and copy and paste code, the code will all run fine with no error. However if I run the entire script from the command line (e.g. `python script.py`) then I get this error. The full error message is:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)`

But to add another twist - sometimes I can run the same python script from the command line with no problem, and others I get this error as above.

If anybody has ideas as to where to specifically look to fix this that'd be great! I'm going to try and do the same thing as before but with the `ls -lha /usr/` output from an 18.04 release, as I only had a 16 release output on hand.

Comment: The suggestion by @dsstorefile1 is good, but try just reinstalling Python.  `apt-get reinstall python2` or `apt-get reinstall python3` from a root terminal might do the trick.  And is easier than reinstalling the entire system.

Comment: Check memory usage when this happens ([link](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-memory-usage/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reinstall All Debian Packages that Involve `/usr`

Run this command to tell `apt` to reinstall every package that puts files in `/usr`:

```
dpkg-query -S '/usr/' |
  sed 's/: .*$//' |
  tr -d ',' |
  xargs apt install -y --reinstall
```

**Warning:** The reinstallation happens without a confirmation prompt.

If you get a message like

> `Package PACKAGE-NAME is not available, but is referred to by another package.`

where `PACKAGE-NAME` is an unobtainable package, you can exclude the package for reinstallation like so:

```
dpkg-query -S '/usr/' |
  sed 's/: .*$//' |
  tr -d ',' |
  tr ' ' '\n' |
  grep -v 'PACKAGE-NAME' |
  xargs apt install -y --reinstall
```

You can chain as many `grep -v` commands as you need.

### Explanation

It's possible that the Ubuntu system you compared with didn't have the same packages installed, which would mean that there could be more files with the wrong permissions inside `/usr`.

By having `apt` reinstall the packages, you can be pretty confident that all the files in `/usr` installed by the operating system have the intended permissions.

---

## Reinstall All pip Packages

*This section assumes that you've installed Python packages with `pip` as root.*

Run this command to reinstall all pip packages:

```
sudo pip freeze --local | xargs sudo pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Run this command to remove Python bytecode files:

```
sudo find /usr/ -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

### Explanation

Since your problem involves Python, I figure there's a chance you installed system-wide Python packages in paths like `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and `/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages`.

When the Python interpreter runs, it also creates bytecode files (`*.pyc`), which may also have had their permissions affected when you recursively messed up your `/usr` folder permissions.  Deleting the `.pyc` files ensures that Python will regenerate them the next time your scripts run.

---

## Reinstall All Debian Packages

If reinstalling just the packages involving a directory didn't fix your problem, there's this more extreme option.

Run this command to tell `apt` to reinstall every package on the system:

```
dpkg --get-selections |
  awk '{if($2=="install"){print $1}}' |
  xargs sudo apt install -y --reinstall
```

**Warning:** The reinstallation happens without a confirmation prompt.

### Explanation

Perhaps something outside of your `/usr` folder broke.

That's what I discovered on 07 February 2018 when I found that a production Debian 8 (jessie) hypervisor had crashed.  The node did not come online after a reboot.

When I loaded up an Ubuntu rescue image, I could not even `chroot` into the broken hypervisor because `/bin/bash` gave me a segmentation fault (kinda like your aborted Python script).  In fact, most of the system files were somehow corrupt.

There was a production virtual machine on this hypervisor that would take quite a bit of effort to redeploy somewhere else because of the broken state of the hypervisor, so I thought to try a repair.

I copied known good Debian 8 binary and library files into the machine until I was able to `chroot` and run `apt` and `dpkg`.  From here, I could instruct `apt` to reinstall the whole system.

After dealing with a few package quirks, every package managed to be reinstalled.  Once I rebooted, the server came back up as if it were never corrupted.

I did have to redeploy the server's Python packages separately because they were bizarrely corrupt as well, but at least the production virtual machine was unharmed.

It's possible to fix a badly broken system by reinstalling what you can.  For the future, I recommend making your server builds as reproducible as possible so that if your software gets [accidentallied](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=accidentally) in any way, you can easily reprovision the system with little effort.